# Changing the sequence numbers of files in Linux

Tags: linux, script, batch-rename

Is it possible to write a script to rename a series of file as below:

- `sol-temp_0010.png`   to   `sol-temp_1.png`
- `sol-temp_0015.png`   to   `sol-temp_2.png`
- `sol-temp_0020.png`   to   `sol-temp_3.png`

etc.?

Comment: What have you tried?  We aren't a script writing service and expect that people do some work up front.  Copy a few to a new folder and try to make something that works - then if/when you run into issues - let us know what you tried and what issues you saw.

Comment: Basic `bash` solution requires: How to use `for` loops, file name wildcards, declaring and using integer variables, and the `mv` command. What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you tried mmv?

Answer (score 1):

The [`rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) command included with Perl (and thus with many Linux distros, too) can do this easily enough:

```
rename 's%(\d+)%$1/5-1%e' sol-temp_*.png
```

The string between the single quotes is evaluated as Perl code and used to modify each filename.

Specifically, `s%foo%bar%` is a regexp match-and-replace operator.  (Usually one would write it as `s/foo/bar/`, but I wanted to use a slash in the replacement, so I chose a different delimiter.)  The regexp `(\d+)` matches the first sequence of one or more digits in the file name and stores it in the `$1` variable for the replacement.  The `e` switch at the end causes the replacement `$1/5-1` to be evaluated as a Perl code, so it returns the number stored in `$1` divided by 10, minus one.

If you don't happen to have the `rename` command installed (or if your `rename` works differently; there are several Unix commands around using that name), but you do have Perl, you can get pretty much the same effect like this:

```
perl -e 'for (<sol-temp_*.png>) {$o = $_; s%(\d+)%$1/5-1%e; rename $o, $_}'
```

Note, however, that this version has no error checking or safeguards against overwriting files; those aren't too hard to add, but the do make the code a bit too long for a one-liner.  If you don't mind writing a full script, though, something like this ought to work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $name (<sol-temp_*.png>) {
    my $orig = $name;

    $name =~ s%(\d+)%$1/5-1%e;   # map "0010" -> "1", "0015" -> "2", etc.

    next if $name eq $orig;
    warn "$0: $name exists, not renaming $orig\n" and next if -e $name;
    rename $orig, $name or warn "$0: error renaming $orig to $name: $!\n";
}
```

(You could even easily modify the script above to read the substitution code and the file names from the command line, just line the `rename` script does, but that's getting beyond the scope of this answer.)